Simple for loop in C preprocessor
My actual use case if for C++. I'm trying to reduce the amount of typing I need to do while explicitly instantiating a template. E.g.,
template <int N>
void myFunc(std::array<float, N> data);

template <>
void myFunc<1>(std::array<float, 1> data);
template <>
void myFunc<2>(std::array<float, 2> data);
template <>
void myFunc<3>(std::array<float, 3> data);
...

What I want is to define a macro / preprocessor definition so that I can do something like pass -D MIN_SIZE 6; -D MAX_SIZE 10 and then do:
BEGIN_PREPROCESSOR_LOOP(SIZE, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE)
template <>
void myFunc<SIZE>(std::array<float, SIZE> data);
END_PREPROCESSOR_LOOP()

Is this possible with (recursive) macros? Or can I use template metaprogramming to generate the explicit specializations?

Check out BOOST_PP_REPEAT and similar macros in boost.preprocessor. They achieve this by pregenerating N boilerplate macros, allowing you to loop up to N iterations. This is impossible to achieve without boilerplate, unless you're willing to list each template argument in the macro call. E.g. something like REPEAT( (1)(2)(3), template <> void myFunc<N_>(std::array<float, N_> data); ) should be doable (probably with a slightly more complex syntax, but the same idea).

Explicit template instantiation for a range of template parameters in C++

Cool! I prefer template metaprogramming. But would does it work for extern template?

`
// foo.h
// No impl in header.
template 
void myFunc(std::array<float, N> data);
// Suppress implicit instantiation.
extern template <>
void myFunc<1>(std::array<float, 1>);
extern template <>
void myFunc<2>(std::array<float, 2>);
extern template <>
void myFunc<3>(std::array<float, 3>);
// foo.cpp
template 
void myFunc(std::array<float, N> data) {
}
template <>
void myFunc<1>(std::array<float, 1>);
template <>
void myFunc<2>(std::array<float, 2>);
template <>
void myFunc<3>(std::array<float, 3>);`
